# Determine when cache will timeout for particular URL

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I would like to look at previously loaded resources in the Chrome or Firefox browsers and see when the browser will consider that resource expired such that it will reload it from the server.

I am interested in doing this for two reasons:

1. Debug problems with appcache.
2. Confirm that I have the server configured properly by looking at resources to see if its expiration time is as I expect.